# Clarity on "One-to-One property"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I was reviewing inverse functions when something occurred to me that left me cloudy. I understand the one-to-one property but there is one example that I am confused on how to tackle. Suppose the expression $x = y^{2}$ existed and the problem asked if the expression was one-to-one. The expression does have every $y$ correspond to one $x$, but it is not a function. However, it does have an inverse function. So is it "one-to-one"?
Summary: Is being a function a pre-requisite for the one-to-one property?

Answer (score 0):

When you have the relationship $x=y^2$, then for every $y$ there is indeed one $x$, but you do not have that for every $x$ there is one $y$. So, it is not one-to-one. In terms of functions, since there is not one $y$ for every $x$, there exists no function from $x$ to $y$ that captures this relationship. So yes, you can say that being one-to-one requires there to be a function both ways.

Answer (score 0):

An [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) (where injective means one-to-one) is by definition a function. I suppose we could talk about non-functions which still satisfy $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$, but we generally mean that $f$ is a function when we are talking about it being one-to-one.

When we're talking about inverses, we are also talking about functions. So a function is invertible if and only if it is bijective (one-to-one and onto). So we can't say that $x=y^2$ is invertible (where $y$ is the dependent variable), since $y$ is not a function here. Also, it is not onto, but this can be easily cured by picking a nice codomain.

Comment: So x=y^2 is not "invertible", but if a question asked me to find the inverse would I still reply with y=x^2

Comment: that's not the inverse though ...

Comment: Technically no, the relation is not a function, and thus does not truly have an inverse. However, some tests ask to "invert" these types of relations, in which case $y=x^2$ will suffice, as long as you take care with the domain and codomain.

Comment: @dave no the values would be $y= \sqrt x$ where  we choose either the positive or other sqrt of x.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee No, that's the relation, not the "inverse".

Comment: Thank you so much @Dave . Im taking Calc I and my teacher decided to not waste time reviewing.

Comment: My pleasure, happy to help.